# PerformanceResourceTiming.transferSize returns 0 in some webpages

Tags: web, request, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I'm trying to get the total transfer size of some web pages. I don't know why but some web pages are returning `0 octets`. I'm trying this snippet to get total transfer size;

```
var fetchedResourcesArray = performance.getEntriesByType("resource");
var totalTransferSize = 0;

for (var resourceIndex = 0; resourceIndex < fetchedResourcesArray.length; resourceIndex++) {
  totalTransferSize += parseInt(fetchedResourcesArray[resourceIndex].transferSize);
}
```

which is very similar to an example of MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/transferSize

When I test this snippet for example on youtube, I don't have any problem getting transfer size in this way but when I try this snippet on twitter, it always returns 0 even it downloads and fetches many resources. How can I track total download size of web apps like twitter?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason for this is to do with CORS. See the note at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API#Resource_loading_timestamps.

> When CORS is in effect, many of these values are returned as zero unless the server's access policy permits these values to be shared. This requires the server providing the resource to send the Timing-Allow-Origin HTTP response header with a value specifying the origin or origins which are allowed to get the restricted timestamp values.
>
> The properties which are returned as 0 by default when loading a resource from a domain other than the one of the web page itself: redirectStart, redirectEnd, domainLookupStart, domainLookupEnd, connectStart, connectEnd, secureConnectionStart, requestStart, and responseStart.

I suspect that some of the elements on those pages come from a different origin (CORS) and the `Timing-Allow-Origin` header is missing.

Comment: I know it doesn't state that transferSize is dependent on this, but this is my findings from when I solved the same issue.